# how do you call the things in the { }

Tags: javascript

for example

```
function myFunction(){
   alert("love");
}
```

things put in `()` are called arguments or parameters, but what the things we put in `{}` are named? operation?

Comment: Kind of unclear question... do you mean code block?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem. This question is more suitable for [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: what about "body of function" or maybe function definition ?

Answer (score 6):

That's the `function body` which is the code that runs when you call the function.

```
function myFunction(args) {
    // this is the function body
    alert("love");
}
```

The [EMCASCript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) refers to it as the ***FunctionBody***.

[image]

See [this description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) for more details where it is referred to as the **"function body"**.

In [this other description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), they call it the **"statements which comprise the body of the function"** which is consistent with "function body".

Answer (score 1):

> FunctionDeclaration :
>   function Identifier ( FormalParameterListopt ) { FunctionBody }

*Function Body* according to [the language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13).

Comment: it might not necessarily be a function that the curly braces enclose, though

Comment: @G.Rassovsky — The question seems to be asking specifically about function bodies.

Comment: it does... but thought its worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

That is called a **Code block**.

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming))

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to "arguments", I'd go with "statements".

For what it's worth:

```
// Here begins the function header
function myFunction(
    a, b, c             // Those are arguments
)
// Here ends the function header
// Here begins the function body
{
    alert("what");
    alert("is");        // And those are statements
    alert("love");
}
// Here ends the function body
```

Answer (score 0):

While in your example it is the function body, whatever is in between curly brackets is a code block. Consider the following example:

`if (true) { do something };`

You can hardly call that a function body. **Code block** is the correct name.

And for people saying "The OP asked about a function definition.", note that OP says "for example".

Comment: The OP asked about a function definition.

Answer (score -1):

You can say a **BLOCK**

{ ~ }

Block also can be used to distinguish coverage of local variable.

Comment: Not in JavaScript. JavaScript does not have block scope, only function scope.

Comment: Yes, if you use `let`. But browsers still have quite some way to go until adopting that. :)